# Finding a generator for a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $$ R:= \mathbb{Q}[X,Y] $$ be a ring of polynomials.

> My question is whether
>   $$  RX \cap RY $$
>   and
>   $$ \{Xa+Yb \mid a,b \in R \} $$
>   are principal ideals by giving a generator.

Definition of the generator:
Let $R$ be a ring. An ideal $I$ is a principal if there exists $g \in I$ so that 
$$ I= Rg .$$

This $g$ is called generator.

I am not sure hot to find such g..also because I am  confused about $ RX $ and $ RY $. How does the set $ \mathbb{Q}[X,Y] X $ look like?

Answer (score 3):

$X,Y$ are coprime in $\Bbb Q[X,Y]$. Therefore any generator of $I:=\;${$Xa+Yb | a,b\in\Bbb Q[X,Y]$} would be a common divisor of $X,Y$ and thus constant. Since $I$ is a proper ideal, i.e. $f(0,0) = 0$ for all $f(x,y)\in I$, then $I$ does not admit constants as they are units. Therefore, $I$ is not a principal ideal.

Finally, again because $X,Y$ are coprime and $\Bbb Q[X,Y]$ is a unique factorization domain then any polynomial divisible by both $X,Y$ is also divisible by $XY$ which itself is a member of the ideal $RX\cap RY$ made of the common multiples of $X$ and $Y$. Therefore, $RX\cap RY = R(XY)$.

Answer (score 0):

If ideal with identity   In this case you can find easily genrators of an ideals because ideal.equl to ring by using  method of findng of genrator of ring  .
  = {ra : r belongs to R } whare R is commutaitive ring with identity 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOa4C.jpg) if uo need explnation you can verify this by taking any iadeal with identity if you not understand  you  can ask about somw eaxmpls agian